# Can't convert from BSON type string to Date on aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 3.4.9, and I want to have monthly report w.r.t. customer info, and here are the Sample example mongodb records with nested items and error received is:

> can't convert from BSON type string to Date

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("59da6a331c7a9ac0b6674fe8"),
"date" : ISODate("2017-10-08T18:10:59.899Z"),
"items" : [ 
    {
        "quantity" : 1,
        "price" : 47.11,
        "desc" : "Item #1"
    }, 
    {
        "quantity" : 2,
        "price" : 42.0,
        "desc" : "Item #2"
    }
],
"custInfo" : "Tobias Trelle, gold customer"
  }

{
"_id" : ObjectId("59da6a511c7a9ac0b6674fed"),
"date" : ISODate("2017-10-08T18:11:28.961Z"),
"items" : [ 
    {
        "quantity" : 1,
        "price" : 47.11,
        "desc" : "Item #1"
    }, 
    {
        "quantity" : 2,
        "price" : 42.0,
        "desc" : "Item #2"
    }
],
"custInfo" : "Tobias Trelle, gold customer"
  }

  {
"_id" : ObjectId("59da6a511c7a9ac0b6674ff0"),
"date" : ISODate("2017-10-08T18:11:29.133Z"),
"items" : [ 
    {
        "quantity" : 1,
        "price" : 47.11,
        "desc" : "Item #1"
    }, 
    {
        "quantity" : 2,
        "price" : 42.0,
        "desc" : "Item #2"
    }
],
"custInfo" : "Tobias Trelle, gold customer"
  }
```

Here is the MongoDB query for calculating sum grouping by `custInfo` month wise

```
db.runCommand({aggregate:"order", pipeline : 
[{$match : {$and : [{"date" : {$gte : ISODate("2016-10-08T18:10:59.899Z")}},
{"date" : {$lte : ISODate("2018-10-08T18:10:59.899Z")}}]}}
, 
{ "$project" : { "custInfo" : 1 ,"count" : 1 ,   "date" : 1 , 
"duration" : {"$month" : [ "date"]}}},
{ "$group" : { "_id" : 
    { "duration" : "$duration" , "custInfo" : "$custInfo"} ,"count" : { "$sum" : 1} }}

    ]}//,
    //cursor:{batchSize:1000}

 )
```

Please help where I was wrong.

Regards
Kris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why `$month` is considered to be "duration" here but in any event, you dropped a dollar sign off the field variable and the call to `$month` was a bit off.   This should work:

```
{ "$project" : { "custInfo" : 1 ,
             "count" : 1 ,
             "date" : 1 ,
             "duration" : {"$month" : "$date" } }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not related with your specific case, but with the generic solution to this BSON error...
Solve this problem with:

```
{"project: { "y.dateFieldName":
 {"$cond":[{ $eq: [{$type: "$data.dateFieldName"},'date']},{"$year":"$data.dateFieldName"},-1]}}
```